# NSProgressIndicator setDoubleValue in NSToolbarItem no work

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6

I put NSProgressIndicator to 2 places(one for window's content view, on for toolbarItem using setView function)

Mac OS X 10.10/Xcode 6.1

the NSProgressIndicator is connected by IB and testing method called "go"
When NSProgressIndicator in window's contentView is work. but in toolbarItem is not work. why?

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator *progressIndicator;

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {

    [progressIndicator setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {

        [progressIndicator setDoubleValue:(double)i];
        [progressIndicator displayIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't really make an outlet to a view in an item in a toolbar. What you set up in the NIB is the prototype for the toolbar item. It's not the actual item at runtime. To find that, you need to enumerate the items in the window's toolbar, find the one(s) with the identifier you assigned to the item that contains the progress indicator, get its view, and use that. If the progress indicator is not the item's sole view — that is, if your item's view contains a view hierarchy and some descendant is the progress indicator — you'll have to find the progress indicator within the view using the usual techniques, such as searching by tag (-viewWithTag:).

Here's example code for the simple case:

```
for (NSToolbarItem* item in self.window.toolbar.items)
{
    if ([item.itemIdentifier isEqualToString:YourIdentifierForTheToolbarItem])
    {
        NSProgressIndicator* progressIndicator = (NSProgressIndicator*)item.view;
        progressIndicator.doubleValue = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still can not get correct result. could you give me a example. thanks in advance.

Comment: Um,  I gave an example. What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: 1.I custom a view and insert a progressIndicator and then connect to progressIndicator by IB. 2.creating a toolbaritem using setview method to the custom view and then add into toolbar. 3.writing a testing method reference to your example to set double value. But It still not work.

Comment: I'm telling you that connecting the outlet in IB is useless. You have to look up the toolbar item based on the identifier in code, like I showed. Also, it's not clear from what you just wrote if the progress indicator is the immediate view of the toolbar item or if you have a container view with a progress indicator inside it. If the latter, you will need to find the progress indicator within the item's view. You can set a tag on the progress indicator in IB and then look it up using `-viewWithTag:`.

Comment: I can't set tag for progressIndicator and I can obtain the progressIndicator address in run time. I do another test is work very well. (change progressIndicator style from bar to spinning and then start animation, It looks work. denote I can obtain the correct progressIndicator address)

Comment: Huh. You're right, you can't set a tag on a progress indicator in IB. That property is read-only on `NSView` and only made read-write on certain subclasses, like `NSControl`. Sorry about that. You can search in different ways by manually enumerating the view hierarchy and examining the view class or `identifier`. Anyway, sounds like you got it working.

Comment: Thanks for replying. in spanning is working, but in bar style still fail.

Comment: Are you just testing with the tight loop you showed in your question? That may not work for a toolbar. Try setting a single value and returning to the event loop.